# Combining two job positions into one on AwesomeCV?

Tags: cv, awesome-cv

I'm using a variant of [awesomeCV](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) and I have two job positions like so: [image]

These are essentially the same employer, I'd like to have both positions (i.e Undergraduate Teaching Assistant & Research Assistant) under the same employer (Ryerson University). Something like:

[image]

The current code for the cls file is:

[image]

And here it is in text: https://pastebin.com/0xs03U4q

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the package source shared in the Github repo in your post, the package already has the function defined for you. You can use the sub-entry function and fill in what ever you want in that format.

```
% Define a subentry of cv information
% Usage: \cvsubentry{<position>}{<title>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cvsubentry}[4]{%
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \setlength\leftskip{0.2cm}
    \subentrytitlestyle{#2} & \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
      {\subentrydatestyle{#3}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
      {}
      {\subentrypositionstyle{#1} & \subentrydatestyle{#3} \\}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}
      {}
      {\multicolumn{2}{L{17.0cm}}{\subdescriptionstyle{#4}} \\}
  \end{tabular*}
}
```

so you can use this function, under any cv-entry you have.

```
\cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\cvsubentry{<position>}{<title>}{<date>}{<description>}
```

With a little novelty, you may use all those pre-defined fields for your own purpose. For instance, you may leave a few of them empty (or fill them with space), or name of the department you work in.